# What is this latency problem that vuex-persist library alludes to?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuex

### Context

On this npm page for [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist), There is a section 'Note on LocalForage and async stores'. The main part is:

> When using asynchronous (promise-based) storages, your state will not
>   be immediately restored into vuex from localForage. It will go into
>   the event loop and will finish when the JS thread is empty. This can
>   invoke a delay of few seconds.

I read [this page](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/) to understand the event loop a bit better. Based on that, localForage (which is promise-based) should use the job queue, and callbacks/thens should execute asap(ish).

I tried to look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/issues/15) but I don't understand the discussion at all. It looked like something was fixed and the issue was closed, but then more comments were added. AND The disclaimer is still on the npm page.

### Question

Can someone explain what all that was about / what was the *technical limitation* that led to a need for this disclaimer (in simple language)? Is it resolved?

Comment: As you say: ASAP *ish*. There will likely be other things in the job queue already, and plenty that gets done immediately, rather than eventually, as your app starts up. This is true of anything async; you can't guarantee when it will get done.

Comment: A few seconds? No, if your thread (and all the promise-queued stuff) does take more than a second to run to completion, something is wrong in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Hrm... I guess it was more a general reminder about how JS works then. And I guess at startup the effect is more noticeable... but if its normal behavior i wonder why it was called out. Anyway thanks v much for your input! :)